# How do i make a div animate diagonally?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am relatively proficient in html and css, but am not with javascript and jquery.  I am trying to get a div to move diagonally, however its not working.
Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#box1 div").animate({left: '+=150', top: '+=150'}, 1000);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
});
</script>
<div id="box1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I know its probably something really stupid, but does anybody know what the problem is?
Thanks!

Comment: Look here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/jtTWy/ You selector should be `$('#box1')` not `$('#box1 div')`. And you have to add some css.

Comment: could also animate the margin instead of position

Comment: This should not be downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

You have to first make it `position: absolute` or `relative` in CSS.

```
#box{
    position: absolute;
}

$("#box1").animate({left: '+=150', top: '+=150'}, 1000);
```

Oh yeah, do this:

```
$("div#box1")   //correct
```

instead of:

```
$("#box1 div")  //incorrect
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bwg8R/

Comment: Ok, well I did this, and its still not doing anything.

Comment: `It's still not doing anything` Well, [my demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bwg8R/) is working. (duh) And I am pretty sure that if it is not working in your code, then there are other problems in your code.

Answer (score 1):

To animate something using `left` and `top` the element needs to be positioned. either `relative` or `absolute`, otherwise `left` and `top` don't do anything to the element.

See my example here: http://jsbin.com/ayafup/edit#html,live

And target your `#box1` element directly as `$(#box1)`, not all child `div`'s inside it as you're doing, `$(#box1 div)`

Also move your scripts down to the bottom before `</body>` for better performance and better practice in general.

Answer (score 0):

Give your div some position because left and top are used after position is set

```
<div id="box1" style="position:absolute;">s</div>
```

And in javascript

```
$("#box1 div").animate({left: '+=150', top: '+=150'}, 1000);
```

Should be

```
$("#box1").animate({left: '+=150', top: '+=150'}, 1000);
```

Because the previos one was selecting child of #box1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution I find for animations effects.. I you don't have any constraint to support older version of browser than animation of you will be like eating a cake..

Try this http://daneden.me/animate/

Cheers...!!!

Comment: You may not know, but is it possible to make something enter diagonally with this?

Comment: yes i guess.. visit the site.. you will get live demos.. of what this css is capable of..